# PHP organising array into product details

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hello all im in need of a little assistance with a array issue.

I have a flat array created from PDF text
the array is product data mixed with other page text
it appears the pattern is

DescriptionCodePrice

then X number of products with

- Descripton
- Product ID
- Price

the data is also not consistant some products have more than 3 rows

a product would be

- Description:  Hemsworth High / Low Level Pan 400(h) x 375(w) x 438(d) mm
- Procuct ID:   INST02009
- Price: £176.00

ive used this for a similar project but its not quite working

```
$transactions = array();
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if ($row['0'] === "DescriptionCodePrice") {
        $transactions[] = array();
     }
     $transactions[count($transactions) - 1][0] = $row;
 }
```

Im trying to extract all the product data into a neat array like so

```
  Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [description] => 
                    [id] => 
                    [price] => 
                 )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [description] => 
                    [id] => 
                    [price] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [description] => 
                    [id] => 
                    [price] => 
                )

         )

 )
```

this is my data

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8        SANITARYWARE  |  HEMSWORTH CLOSE COUPLEDPrices include VAT  
    [1] => DescriptionCodePrice
    [2] => Hemsworth Close Coupled Pan 
    [3] => 421(h) x 373(w) x 673(d) mm INST02007
    [4] => £206.00 
    [5] => Hemsworth Close Coupled 
    [6] => Cistern 481(w) mm INST02001
    [7] => £170.00 
    [8] => Hemsworth Basin 605mm  
    [9] => Two Taphole INST02003
    [10] => £172.00
    [11] => Hemsworth Pedestal INST02008£84.00
    [12] => Hemsworth Soft Close Bar 
    [13] => Hinge Seat - Solid Natural Oak INST02011
    [14] => £147.00
    [15] => Total £779.00   
    [16] => Hemsworth Close Coupled WC Suite
    [17] => Description CodePrice
    [18] => Hemsworth Close Coupled Pan 
    [19] => 421(h) x 373(w) x 673(d) mm INST02007
    [20] => £206.00
    [21] => Hemsworth Close Coupled 
    [22] => Cistern 481(w) mm INST02001
    [23] => £170.00
    [24] => Hemsworth Soft Close Bar 
    [25] => Hinge Seat - Solid Natural Oak INST02011
    [26] => £147.00
    [27] => Hemsworth Soft Close Bar 
    [28] => Hinge Seat - White INST02012
    [29] => £132.00 
    [30] => Hemsworth   
    [31] => Hemsworth Basin 605mm
    [32] => Description CodePrice
    [33] => Hemsworth Basin 605mm  
    [34] => Two Taphole INST02003
    [35] => £172.00
    [36] => Hemsworth Basin 605mm  
    [37] => One Taphole INST02010
    [38] => £172.00
    [39] => Hemsworth Cloakroom Basin 
    [40] => 500 x 305mm Two Taphole  INST02013
    [41] => £144.00
    [42] => Hemsworth Pedestal (Fits 
    [43] => 605mm and 500mm basin) INST02008
    [44] => £84.00  
    [45] => £256.   00  
    [46] => Hemsworth Basin 
    [47] => 605mm Two Taphole   
    [48] => & Pedestal   
    [49] => (Taps not included) 
    [50] => £523.   00  
    [51] => Hemsworth Close  Coupled WC with  Oak Seat  
    [52] => Hemsworth Suite with Close  
    [53] => Coupled Cistern WC & Basin  
  )
```

My current page code is

```
require_once("vendor/autoload.php"); 

// Parse pdf file and build necessary objects.
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('Instinct-Autumn-Bathroom-Catalogue-2018- 
pages/page-9.pdf');

// Retrieve all pages from the pdf file.
$pages  = $pdf->getPages();

// Loop over each page to extract text.
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $array = explode("\n", $page->getText());
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo '<br><br>';
}

// Split array into transactions
$transactions = array();
foreach ($array as $row) {
  if ($row['0'] === "DescriptionCodePrice") {
      $transactions[] = array();
  }
  $transactions[count($transactions) - 1][0] = $row;
}
```

Comment: How are you extracting the data in the first place?

Comment: im using https://pdfparser.org/documentation  and it gives me the data from the PDF in text 

im then adding each new line into an array

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

First remove the headers. (It looks like you actually have two headers you don't want, not just "DescriptionCodePrice".)

```
array_splice($data, 0, 2);
```

Split the remaining data into chunks of three and combine each chunk with the string keys to produce the result.

```
$keys = ['title', 'description', 'price'];

$result['products'] = array_map(function ($item) use ($keys) {
    return array_combine($keys, $item);
}, array_chunk($data, 3));
```

Comment: this almost works  its just adding the extra unwanted data

Comment: some of the products are over 3 lines and some are over 4   because of this inconsistency its not accurate as the data is mixed up

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the extra rows in the array when I wrote this. I'm about to go eat lunch but I'll look at it again after. :-)

Comment: Thank You..  i have looked at other PDF pages i have to do and they are a similar format just the amount on rows for each product can vary

Comment: to give you more of an idea 
this is each PDF page extracted into arrays

you can see the inconsistency 

i think i will have to tweak the code per page

http://myboxproject.co.uk/pdf/test.php
the parsed PDF

http://myboxproject.co.uk/pdf/Instinct-Autumn-Bathroom-Catalogue-2018.pdf